# Workflow Status suspended for particular user

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have an Issue with Approval Workflow.
I have one people picker column **HRManager**, there is problem with one User , if i pick that user **xyz** the workflow automatically going to **Suspended** Status.

How can i reslove this issue please share your ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

When the Automatically update the workflow status to the current stage name option is selected in SharePoint Designer, SharePoint must edit the list page to change the workflow status. A user needs edit permissions on the list to edit the workflow status. If a user does not have edit permissions on the list, the workflow enters a suspended state.

Answer (score 0):

please check that user's email id is it valid.please check its email id before assigning the task. I think its email id is not configured.

please refer link:

http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/an-unhandled-exception-occurred-during-the-execution-of-the-workflow-21994.aspx